# Loopback source IP Spoofing

Tags: network, spoofing, udp

Assuming I have a service running with elevated privileges on a host, and another service is listening on a UDP port with access for everyone (0.0.0.0) is it possible to craft a spoofed UDP datagram from localhost so that appears it comes from a remote address? Is there some limitation because different network interfaces are used (eg. loopback vs eth0)? Finally, if feasable, are there any (local) mitigations besides changing the protocol to ask the remote address for confirmation?

I can't inject or alter in any other way the other service.

Comment: You can craft a spoofed UDP packet with Scapy python library , probably some code you can copy/paste out there.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/what-happens-if-the-localhost-does-not-interpret-127-0-0-1-as-the-loopback-addre may be worth checking out. Most likely, any TCP stack will reject the packet due to all RFCs quoted there. But it would be implementation specific.

Comment: You might look at OpenBSD's [Unicast Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/filter.html#urpf), if I understand your question correctly.